# ruby here documents

Tags: ruby, string, heredoc, string-interpolation

I am trying to write a method in Ruby that uses a here-document of HTML code with input variables and fills them in accordingly.

My method is:

```
calcForm(left, op, right, result)
```

The html tags I am using are

```
<input type="text" name="left" value="?????"> 
<select name="op">
<option value="add" ?????>+</option>
<option value="mul" ?????>*</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="right" value="?????"> 
=
?????
```

Everywhere there are question marks my method has to fill in with variables left, op, right, and result.

For example,

```
calcForm(6, "mul", 7, 42)
```

should return the string:

```
<input type="text" name="left" value="**6**"> 
<select name="op">
<option value="add">+</option>
<option value="mul" **selected**>*</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="right" value="**7**"> 
=
**42**
```

So, the word "selected" should appear after "add" or "jul" depending on the value of op, the values of left and right should be filled in in value = "...", and the result should appear on the last line.

I am new to ruby but this is what I have done so far with my knowledge of here docs:

```
the_tags = <<HERE
<input type="text" name="left" value=#{left}> 
<select name="op">
<option value="add" #{op}>+</option>
<option value="mul" #{op}>*</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="right" value=#{right}> 
=
#{result}
HERE

def calcForm(left,op,right,result)
```

I am stuck at this point. I am confused at how to connect my method calcForm to the here document above.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: You might want to look into the [dom gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/dom) that I have developed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like you're thinking of a heredoc as a sort of template, that you define once, with string interpolations built in, and then reuse.  It isn't.  As with any string definition, the string interpolation happens on the fly when the variable is defined.

So you would just do

```
def calcForm(left,op,right,result)
   <<HERE
     <input type="text" name="left" value=#{left}> 
     <select name="op">
     <option value="add" #{op}>+</option>
     <option value="mul" #{op}>*</option> 
     </select>
     <input type="text" name="right" value=#{right}> 
     =
     #{result}
   HERE
end
```

However, a better approach for what you're trying to do might be [ERB](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/ERB.html), which works more like what you had in mind above; i.e. it is a template.

```
require 'erb'
template = ERB.new <<HERE
         <input type="text" name="left" value=<%=left%>> 
         <select name="op">
         <option value="add" <%=op%>>+</option>
         <option value="mul" <%=op%>>*</option> 
         </select>
         <input type="text" name="right" value=<%=right%>> 
         =
         <%=result%>
         HERE

def calcForm(left,op,right,result)
   template.result(binding)    
end
```

Note that `binding` here is a magic word that means "evaluate the expression in the current context"; i.e. with the currently defined variables (the parameters that were passed in).

Comment: +1 for the simple use of ERB, I didn't know you could use it so easily like that.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest answer is to define and return the string inside your method, and use the parameter names as the interpolation variables.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
def calcForm(left,op,right,result)
  <<HERE
<input type="text" name="left" value="#{left}"> 
<select name="op">
<option value="add" #{'selected' if op == 'add'}>+</option>
<option value="mul" #{'selected' if op == 'mul'}>*</option> 
</select>
<input type="text" name="right" value="#{right}"> 
=
#{result}
HERE
end
```

I added some quotes around your attributes to help with HTML validation.  You don't need to explicitly write `return` or declare a local variable because the return value of the method will always be the value of the last ruby expression.

Comment: Great this is simple and it seems to work! Still have another quick question if you don't mind. Depending on the value of variable "op" I need to add the string "selected" after either "add" or "mul" in the html tag. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I have edited my answer to do what you wanted.  Basically you can put any ruby code inside the `#{}`, so I put `'selected' if op == 'add'`.  This expression will evaluate to either `'selected'` or `nil` depending on the situation.