# Can I 'refresh' a value of a variable?

Tags: ruby, variable-declaration

I declare steps that need to be done in order to install wordpress in an array in the beginning of my ruby script

```
$wordpress_cmds = [ "mkdir -p #{$web_root}#{$web_directory}#{$web_url}/public_html",
                    "cp -R #{$wordpress_current}/*  #{$web_root}#{$web_directory}#{$web_url}/public_html",
                    "chown -R www-data:www-data #{$web_root}#{$web_directory}#{$web_url}",
                 ]
```

Some of the variables are updated later on. Is there any way to get the latest values of all variables that are in the array when accessing the arrya?

Let's say that if my code is like I always get the initial value of the array not the one I want (with updated variables inside)

```
$web_root = '====='
$wordpress_cmds = ["#{$web_root}"]

puts $wordpress_cmds[0]
$web_root= "new value"
puts $wordpress_cmds[0] 
$web_root.replace("new value")
puts $wordpress_cmds[0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, string interpolation is one-time operation. It modifies the string by substituting values and that's it. However,  with a slightly modified code you can do like this:

```
$web_root = '====='
$wordpress_cmds = [lambda{"mkdir -p #{$web_root}#{$web_directory}#{$web_url}/public_html"}]

puts $wordpress_cmds[0].call
$web_root= "new value"
puts $wordpress_cmds[0].call 
$web_root.replace("new value")
puts $wordpress_cmds[0].call
```

Output:

```
=====
new value
new value
```

Here instead of string you put a function into array. That function will return an actual value of your variable. So, you have to do `$wordpress_cmds[0].call` instead of `$wordpress_cmds[0]` to actually invoke it.

Comment: How to change my code if I have more "complex" string? `"mkdir -p #{$web_root}#{$web_directory}#{$web_url}/public_html",
`

Comment: Great. Thank you. Especially for the explanation. Works smoothly.

Comment: Another option for doing the same kind of thing is to use erb -- see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/8131635/1237

Comment: @JacobM: that's an option too, +1'd

Comment: I was thinking about that too. But wanted to know if there is any other option.